How do I read a Riverpod provider within a Class or Stream without Ref or context?
I have a Class I use for backend, within which I have a Stream that Streams data from Firebase, as shown below. I need to access the data from a Riverpod Provider to specify the Firebase collection reference (yearFromProvider2).
How can this be done from within a Class that does not have any access to ref or context.
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userStream() async* {
    //Need to read another Stream here to access the value of year to add to collection reference
    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(yearFromProvider2)
        .doc("test")
        .snapshots();
  }

In all other parts of my app I would use StreamProvider and call it as follows:
    final data = ref.watch(provider).value;

This cannot be done within the Class as I do not have any access to Ref or the BuildContext. Is there any quick solution to read an instance of the Provider2?

You don't.  The provider lives inside the object pointed to by ref.  Without ref, there's no access.

I see, thanks. Do you have a suggestion as to how to feed my Stream with a value from another Stream (i.e., from firebase)? thanks

Use a provider that can consume a stream.  Make it a family if you need to have it parameterized.

I typically wrap a StreamProvider immediately around any stream that an API sends me, to shift from Stream protocol to ProviderListenable protocol (the protocol of Riverpod).

Thanks, I guess I am looking for a simpler implementation. I only need to access the values from my Stream once but in several places across my services. Is there a method to read an instance of the stream and use that? I am not using any widgets with build methods so cannot see a way to access ref. Thanks in advance, I am new to riverpod.

If the values don't need to be observable, don't bother with riverpod.  Just create a class that reads the stream and stashes the relevant values, available upon demand to a static method.

Thank you very much @RandalSchwartz. I'm new to Flutter and am not up to speed with best practices. This is very helpful and solves my issue, thanks
